# javascript split array - do a calculation - and merge again

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following array:

```
fruits = [{"fruit":"banana","amount":"2","price":"1"},{"fruit":"apple","amount":"5","price":"2"},{"fruit":"kiwi","amount":"1","price":"5"}]
```

How can I get the same array but the value price contains the value from amountxprice?

final result should look like this:

```
fruits = [{"fruit":"banana","amount":"2","price":"2"},{"fruit":"apple","amount":"5","price":"10"},{"fruit":"kiwi","amount":"1","price":"5"}]
```

Comment: Where is `amountxprice` defined?

Comment: Why are the numbers stored as strings?

Comment: With `amountxprice` OP probably means `amount * price`

Comment: Don't do that. It's more reliable to *always* compute the final (amount*price) dynamically. What if the amount changes for some reason? Your way requires a second update of the price as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply loop the array and do the calculation :

```
for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) fruits[i].price *= fruits[i].amount;
```

But note that you'll lose your original array.

You might want to add a property instead :

```
for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++)
    fruits[i].finalPrice = fruits[i].price * fruits[i].amount;
```

Comment: or with jQuery: `$(fruits).each(function(index, item) { item.price *= item.amount; });`

Comment: Yeah he could but it would be like that : `$.each(fruits, function(){})`. But I wouldn't use jQuery for such a simple task!

Comment: yet another variant [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)